# Harddisk formatting with dd return error

Tags: linux, hard-drive, dd

I tried to format my harddisk (160 GB) with the following command

```
dd   if=/dev/zero   of=/dev/sda
```

After some 3 hours, following error came up:

```
dd: writing to '/dev/sda' : No space left on device 
312581809+0 records in 
312581808+0 records out 
160041885696 bytes (160 GB) copied, 10708.3 s, 14.9 MB/s
```

Any idea what went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, if you wanted to wipe a disk 'shred' is the proper command. You'd then want to create partitions with fdisk, and use some variety of mk__fs (mke2fs etc) or parted to make a file system in the partition.

Comment: i think *mke2fs* is usually just a symlink to *mkfs.ext2* or similar.  at least on my Debian system there isn't even a *mke2fs* command available; it's all *mkfs.whatever* ... but yes, if one is trying to "format a drive" meaning "prepare a filesystem", these are the needed steps.

Answer (score 4):

`/dev/zero` is in principle infinite. `/dev/sda` is not.

Comment: And that is why dd was not able to put more of it to the disk: mission accomplished, nothing went wrong.

Comment: Thanks but is it then now a proper way of formatting a harddisk?

Comment: @usman: well, i would not call "whiping out the disk with zeros" "formating". but it did what you wanted, right?

Comment: Yes it did what I want but what do you suggest to 'format' a harddisk.